# My ionic.css always overwrite when I run ionic lib update, why?

Tags: css, ionic-framework

For example: I changed this line in my *www/lib/ionic/css/ionic.css* file:

```
background-color: #f39200;
```

But always that I run **ionic lib update** this line change to an older version:

```
background-color: #11c1f3;
```

Why?

Comment: Do you have a scss/ionic.app.scss?

Comment: @theblindprophet Yes.

Comment: Have you ever ran `gulp sass`? Or messed with SASS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ionic.css` file is being overwritten when the `ionic.scss` file is compiled. Your directory should look as such:

```
...
resources/
scss/
    ionic.app.scss
www/
   css/
      style.css
   lib/
      css/
         ionic.css
      scss/
         ionic.scss
...
```

All you need to do is edit such styles inside of `style.css`. `ionic.css` is compiled straight from `ionic.scss` and therefore is overwritten every time you save. If you want to use pure CSS only then make sure to write all of your styles inside `style.css`.

If you want to use SASS then write your styles inside `scss/ionic.app.scss` and run `gulp sass`.

The `index.html` that is built at the beginning explains this to some extent:

```
<link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
<link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
-->
```

Comment: I just ran setup sass and now worked! Thank you very much!!

Comment: No problem. Happy coding.